# How to set URL from ionic tabs project?

Tags: ionic3, router, progressive-web-apps, ionic-native

I create an Ionic tabs project and now whenever I'm using NavController I'm using `navCtrl.setRoot("PageName");`  Or `nacCtrl.push("PageName");` 
I want to set the URL for the Pages. For example, if I'm on ProfilePage then I should be able to access the page from localhost:8100/profile. But right now I can't because this navCtrl doesn't allow me to do this. So what is the best practice to do this because I want to make my app as a PWA App.

Comment: You may follow this [tutorial](https://blog.ionicframework.com/how-to-make-pwas-with-ionic/) on how to deploy your Ionic app as a PWA. Ionic has an impressive deep-linking feature that works great with PWAs. Also, with the update to Ionic-angular 3, they created an `IonicPage` module which lets us add, among other things, a static (or dynamic) URL for pages.

Comment: Thanks @abielita that tutorial helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [tutorial](https://blog.ionicframework.com/how-to-make-pwas-with-ionic/) on how to deploy your Ionic app as a PWA. Ionic has an impressive deep-linking feature that works great with PWAs. Also, with the update to Ionic-angular 3, they created an `IonicPage` module which lets us add, among other things, a static (or dynamic) URL for pages.